# What are methods to distribute volumes over a calendar in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

Currently I am conceptually stuck on how to proceed with the issue below. I am basically having a list with Sold Items per country and item type.

My output should be a calendar with the returned items per item type and country.

The first dataframe that specifies the `order_date`, `Type`, `Country` and `Volume`.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'order_date': ['01.02.2020', '01.02.2020'], 'Type': ['Book', 'CD'], 'Country':['IT','AT'], 'Volume':[300,4000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

This is basically just a list of Sold Items per day per country and item type.

```
Index  order_date   Type    Country   Volume
0      01.02.2020   Book    IT        300
1      01.02.2020   CD      AT        4000
```

My second dataframe would be:

```
d2 = {'return-t[d]': [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4], 'Type': ['Book', 'CD','Book', 'CD','Book', 'CD','Book', 'CD','Book', 'CD','Book', 'CD','Book', 'CD','Book', 'CD','Book', 'CD','Book', 'CD'], 'Country':['IT','AT','IT','AT','IT','AT','IT','AT','IT','AT','IT','AT','IT','AT','IT','AT','IT','AT','IT','AT'], 'distr-percentage':[0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01, 0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01, 0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01, 0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2,index=None)
df2
```

This is based on my analysis of returned items. `order_date` + `return-t[d]` is the return date. For example the share of sold books in italy that gets returned on `order_date`+ 0 days is 0.01.

```
   return-t[d]  Type    Country  distr-percentage
0   0           Book    IT       0.01
1   0           CD      AT       0.01
2   0           Book    IT       0.01
3   0           CD      AT       0.01
4   1           Book    IT       0.01
5   1           CD      AT       0.01
6   1           Book    IT       0.01
7   1           CD      AT       0.01
```

My problem now is that I am stuck on how to proceed. I want to create a simple calendar that gives information how many returned items on that date.
The only thing I could think of was creating another calendar in the columns and distribute the volumes there and in the end group by the date columns. But seemed like overkill.

Comment: im not sure i understand the logic here, are you trying to merge your 2 dataframes on `Country` and `Type`? Can you give an expected output with your overkill approach

Comment: @Kenan I sell 300 books to Italy on the 01.02.2020. Assuming 100% will be returned, I know that all of them will be returned in the next 100 days. If it would just be this one entry I would know that I have to create a calendar from 01.02.2020 + 99 days for books in italy and multiply the sold items volume * share for the respecte return time. And then I would know how many returns i have on which day. But I want to do this with many more conditions as you can tell from the convoluted mess above.